# How can I add a custom CSS class to checkboxes labels?

Tags: 8, forms

I'm using Drupal 8 with the Form API and the AJAX API, now I want to add a custom CSS class to every checkbox label, because I need to use the bootstrap custom checkboxes.

PHP (slimmed):

```php
$form['colors'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => array('1' => $this->t('Black'), '2' => $this->t('White')),
    '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['custom-control-input'],
    ],
    '#prefix' => '<div class="foobar">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>'
);
```

HTML Result (please notice every label has the class "option"):

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <div class="foobar">
    <div id="edit-colors" class="form-checkboxes">
      <div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-checkbox form-item-colors-1 js-form-item-colors-1">
        <input
          class="custom-control-input form-checkbox"
          data-drupal-selector="edit-colors-1"
          data-msg-required="Black is required."
          type="checkbox"
          id="edit-colors-1"
          name="colors[1]"
          value="1"
        />
        <label for="edit-colors-1" class="option">Black</label>
      </div>
      <div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-checkbox form-item-colors-2 js-form-item-colors-2">
        <input
          class="custom-control-input form-checkbox"
          data-drupal-selector="edit-colors-2"
          data-msg-required="White is required."
          type="checkbox"
          id="edit-colors-2"
          name="colors[2]"
          value="2"
        />
        <label for="edit-colors-2" class="option">White</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Twig Code:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
 {{form.colors}}
</div>
```

I know about the "**template_preprocess_form_element**" function, but I had no luck.

Do you guys have any ideas or tipps? Is there a simple way to modify the label class, or should I try the "Form Options Attributes" Plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to issue [#2774255](https://www.drupal.org/node/2774255) and [line 38 in the FormElementLabelTest.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.7.8/core/modules/system/tests/src/Kernel/Form/FormElementLabelTest.php#L38) you should be able to use `#label_attributes` for this.

> ```
> '#label_attributes' => ['class' => ['meow']],
> ```

---

Update: Seems you can also try to do this by implementing [`template_preprocess_form_element`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21form.inc/function/template_preprocess_form_element/8.7.x). There's an example on [line 493 in the form.inc](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.7.8/core/includes/form.inc#L493). In your theme implement `template_preprocess_form_element` and hopefully you find some unique identifiers in there to have this class added only for elements in certain forms or elements of certain types. And then it's

```
$variables['label']['#attributes'] => ['class' => ['meow']]
```

---

Last but not least there's the new [Formdazzle!](https://www.drupal.org/project/formdazzle) module you could try to use to override the label element templates directly.

> #### Drupal form theming with less pain
>
> Theming Drupal forms can be difficult and time-consuming. This module
>   provides a set of utilities that make form theming easier.
>
> Currently, this module provides theme suggestions for forms that are
>   much more useful than those provided by Drupal core.
>
> - Theme suggestions for all form elements (including buttons)
> - Theme suggestions for all form element labels
> - All theme suggestions include the form ID and the form element name; e.g. `[element-type]--[form-id]--[form-element-name].html.twig`

Comment: It's working, but only for form type "textfield". If I add this option "#label_attributes" to a textfield, the label class gets overwritten with "meow", as expected. If I try this with checkboxes. Nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you for the tipp! We got it!

```function template_preprocess_form_element(&$variables)
{
  if ($variables['element']['#type'] == 'checkbox') {
    $variables['label']['#attributes'] = ['class' => ['custom-control-label']];
  }
}
```

Comment: `label_attributes` on checkboxes worked fine for me.