# How do I add a class on a "checkboxes" element's option?

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I have an exposed field with a "checkboxes" field, that I need to theme by adding (and removing) Drupal's default classes. I found close to nothing about how to do that, excepted [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/287471/74912).

So, I did the following thing:

```php
function MY_THEME_preprocess_form_element(array $variables) {
  $elements = $variables['element'];
  if ($elements['#type'] == 'checkbox' && strpos($elements['#attributes']['id'], 'field-news-tag')) {
    $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'c-tag-filters__item__input';
  }
}
```

I had to use `strpos()` because the checkboxes are related to a taxonomy term, so the id is different, with the taxonomy term id added at the end. My code, as is, doesn't return any error but no class is added to the checkbox.

Am I on the right track? Or is this doable only from the `hook_form_alter()` ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look in the function sig - `array $variables` - you're throwing away changes to `$variables`. Make sure you're taking it by reference instead (`array &$variables`)

Comment: I changed `$variables` for `&$variables`, sadly didn't work

Comment: just an idea - you can achieve the result within twig templates - there you can get all the classes which will be rendered and add/remove any you want. Reference https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2347511

Comment: I've overriden a `form-element.html.twig` template where I can do whatever I want with the label, but the input itself is just a Markup string. Is there a way to do so in the form-element, or should I override something else?